# Why Views and partial views have the same cshtml file extension in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm learning some [basic stuffs in razor](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax). I'm a little confused about the extension file: views and partial views seem to share the same extension **cshtml**. I thought that was a mistake on my behalf, but I've re-checked the checkbox, I get the same extension for both types of files.

Besides, with webform view engine, it's easier to locate views by their colors or/and extensions (View are white-.aspx, Partial are yellow-.ascx, Master are white/blue-.master)

If that's the way it has to be now, why would views and partial views share the same extension? **Is there any reason they made them all have the same extension?**

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Razor views and partial views don't need a seperate file extension because both use the same base class.

In contrast, WebForms (ASPX) pages, user controls, and master pages all derive from different base classes which is why the distinction was necessary. It's simply a result of design decisions made during the creation of Asp.Net WebForms.

Comment: That make sens. But, are they going to make them differ by the icon color in the solution explorer? Just to make people locate different type of file easily? Just to make things easier when there are many files in the same folder.

Comment: @Richard77 an easy way to make the distinction would be to create a naming convention. Example: your masterpage could be `_Layout.cshtml` and your partials could be `ViewNamePartial.cshtml`

Comment: Since the extension is the same there is no way to distinguish between the two file roles. A naming convention is best for such a purpose.

Comment: Well, that's a interesting. Thanks.